# echo inside a value to be outputted as echo | PHP

Tags: php, html, echo, sqlsrv

May I ask, how are we able to put echo inside a variable that is subjected to be echoed out?

This is the code.

I'm trying to put in the `values=""` the `$user['firstname']` and `$user['lastname']`

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
$out .= "
<div class='form-group' > <!-- hidden-->
<label for='postedby' class='col-sm-3 control-label'>Posted By</label>
<div class='col-sm-9'>
<input type='text' class='form-control' id='postedby' name='postedby' 
value='$user['firstname'] $user['lastname']' style='text-transform:uppercase;width:90%' >
</div></div>
";
    }

    echo $out;
?>
```

Is there a way to do this? Echo inside echo?

Comment: There is a way, but why? Use String concatenation and make one output only..

Comment: @LarsStegelitz, this code is for a modal. That's why I structured it like that.

Comment: Try without the inner quotes - `$user[firstname] $user[lastname]`

Comment: @NigelRen, it outputs as 1 and 1

Comment: if you'd have to use arrays in strings without concatenation, wrap it with curly braces: `$mystring = "Hello {$user['fistname']}";`, however, string concatenation is the preferred way (see below)

Comment: This is one way to do it. I'll check on this as well. Thanks @LarsStegelitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$out = '';
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
$out .= '<div class="form-group" > <!-- hidden-->
<label for="postedby" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Posted By</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="postedby" name="postedby" 
value="'.$user['firstname'].' '.$user['lastname'].'" style="text-transform:uppercase;width:90%">
</div></div>';
    }
    echo $out;
```

you've to **concat** firstname and lastname.

Answer (score 0):

Just put brackets around each variable, php will do the rest.

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){ 

    $out .= " <div class='form-group' >
       <!-- hidden--> 
           <label for='postedby' class='col-sm-3 control-label'>Posted By</label>
           <div class='col-sm-9'>
               <input type='text' class='form-control' id='postedby' name='postedby' value='{$user['firstname']} {$user['lastname']}' style='text-transform:uppercase;width:90%' >
           </div>
       </div> ";
} 

echo $out; ?>
```